# Ghost lines on box-shadow: inset, not inset;

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, storybook

when using `box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #0e0f0c inset, 0 0 0 1px #0e0f0c;

```
box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #0e0f0c inset, 0 0 0 1px #0e0f0c;
border-radius: 8px;
```

I get ghost lines in between shadows. For testing reasons I cannot use outline to mimic the same style.

[image: ghost lines]

What is the solution here or why does it happen?

Answer (score 0):

It could be a browser rendering issue. It depends on your device graphics capabilities. At some zoom levels the ghost lines possibly might not be visible.

I tried to replicate the same, but the ghost lines are not appearing on my device. These sort of rendering inconsistencies can be observed from device to device.